# Rails adding extra line in my redis cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

Im using [redis-rails](https://github.com/redis-store/redis-rails) in my project to store a cache of users, and I don't know why a extra line is added at begining of cache.

This is my config:

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, {
  host: ENV['REDIS_SERVER'] || 'localhost',
  port: 6379,
  db: 0,
  namespace: ENV['CUSTOMER']
}
```

This is my code:

```
namespace :update_employees_cache do
  desc "Update employees cache"
  task update: :environment do
    employees = []

    Employee.where(active: true).each do |item|
      employees.push({ id: item.id, name: item.name })
    end

    Rails.cache.write "employees", employees.to_json
  end
end
```

This is the result
[image: Result]

At line 1, `o: ActiveSupport::Cache::Entry:@valueI"�`

What is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After open a issue in the project repo I discovered that is the default behavior of rails wrapping the cache with that data.

In my case I need to avoid it, then is needed set `row` as `true` in configs.

```
config.cache_store = :redis_store, {
  host: ENV['REDIS_SERVER'] || 'localhost',
  port: 6379,
  db: 0,
  namespace: ENV['CUSTOMER'],
  raw: true
}
```